# React Native Notification Icon Not working

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, icons, react-native-fcm

I've added and generated notification icons which have white fill and transparent background but still white box is appearing in the notification tray.

I'm sending notifications from server. What's the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took out the answer my self.
Above implementation is correct, but I was sending icon field from the server too, i think that was overriding. After removing that, it worked charming!